# Pseudocode to Java

Tags: java, pseudocode

I'm having problems with the inner loop of the pseudocode with the error Array index out of range: 0.

here's the part of Java I've done

```
import java.util.Stack;

class stack {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] number = {23, 7, 9, 10, 0, 18, 7, 38, 0, 15, 36, 0, 42, 63, 8, 19, 28, 0};
    Stack<Integer> S1 = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> Q1 = new Stack<Integer>();

    for (int x : number) {
        if (x != 0) {
            S1.push(x);
            Q1.add(x);
        } else {
            S1.remove(x);
            S1.remove(x);
            System.out.println("Popped element: " + S1.pop());

            if (S1 != 0) {    //<- error here Array index out of range: 0
                S1.remove(x);      
                Q1.add(x);
                Q1.remove(x);
            }

            System.out.println("S1 " + S1);
            System.out.println("Q1 " + Q1);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: `if (S1 != 0)` you're supposed to check if S1 is empty. here you are comparing it to zero. that's hardly the same? though error message is something you would not get either..

Comment: how can i edit to the way the pseudocode code works in java?

Comment: to find out which methods Stack has, check its javadoc.

Comment: I think, in the first `for loop` you suppose to take `input` from `file` or `user`!

Comment: The data is given in the codes under int[] number

Comment: S1 can't even be null.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, I would expect the compiler to throw an exception on the `S1!=0`
Here you are comparing the entire stack with a single value. what you want to check if if the stack still contains anything. You can do that by using the `.empty()` method to check if it's empty or not

the total code becomes this then

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[] number = { 3, 27, 9, 0, 61, 38, 14, 48, 25, 19, 7, 0, 24, 39, 8, 29, 14, 0 };
            Stack<Integer> S1 = new Stack<Integer>();
            Stack<Integer> Q1 = new Stack<Integer>();

            for (int x : number) {
                if (x != 0) {
                    S1.push(x);
                    Q1.add(x);
                } else {
                    S1.remove(x);
                    S1.remove(x);
                    System.out.println("Popped element: " + S1.pop());

                    if (!S1.empty()) {
                        S1.remove(x);
                        Q1.add(x);
                        Q1.remove(x);
                    }

                    System.out.println("S1 " + S1);
                    System.out.println("Q1 " + Q1);
                }
            }
}
```

To be honest, I'm not quite sure what the code is supposed to do, but with the change in the if check, your index error will be fixed